# Windows 10 -System has blocked Quicken from accessing the following file/folder: c:\users\Admin\AppData\roaming\Intuit so Quicken won't start up

Tags: windows, appdata, quicken

Not sure why this is happening.
Spent hours on the phone with Quicken, with no resolution.

Two unexplained issues about this error. That folder - AppData\Roaming\Intuit doesn't exist and Quicken doesn't create that folder anymore. Their AppData\Roaming file is named "Quicken."

The other weird event is that when I created a new local user on this Windows 10 computer, the quicken files open without an issue.

All the security permissions are "allow"

Hope someone can explain and resolve this issue.

Comment: I created a new local user on this Windows 10 computer, the quicken files open without an issue.   ....  That means a damaged user profile for the other userid.   Also make sure the Data file is in Documents - not AppData

Comment: yes, the data file is in Documents.

Comment: That probably means the userid you referred to is damaged.

Comment: The userid is my admin account. It was the only user on this windows 10 computer before having this Quicken issue. How do it repair the damage?

Answer (score 0):

> The userid is my admin account. It was the only user on this windows
> 10 computer before having this Quicken issue. How do it repair the
> damage?

You cannot repair a damaged user profile in any practical way.

Two ways forward:

(A)  Log into the existing Admin account (your only one). Make a new, test User Account and make it a member of Administrators (be certain of this step).

Back up all documents, pictures, videos, favorites, email and everything. Make a folder c:\temp and back it up to c:\temp or to a USB drive.

Log into the new test Admin account, and delete the other admin account (this is why you need careful backups).

Restart and make your regular User Account and make it a member of Administrators.

Log into your Account and restore documents, email and all from c:\temp.

You need to work very carefully and ensure backups.

Some persons find it easier to do a complete backup and reinstall Windows.

A regular Repair Install will NOT fix a damaged user profile.

Good luck with this.